# Django edit model template - How do I only select the text value to show in an edit template of a (foreign key) model dropdown?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on an edit view for my model that has a reference to another table. 
The model I am working with looks like this:

```
class SkillSet(models.Model):
SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'None'),
    (1, 'Basic'),
    (2, 'User'),
    (3, 'Advanced'),
    )

rating = models.ForeignKey(Rating, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
skillLevel = models.IntegerField(choices = SKILL_LEVEL_CHOICES, default = 0)
notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I created a form for it that you can see here:

```
class SkillSetEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = SkillSet
    fields = [
        "skill",
        "skillLevel",
        "notes"
        ]
    labels = {
        'skill': ('Skill'),
        'skillLevel': ('Skill Level'),
        'notes': ('Notes'),
    }
```

and after that I put it inside my view like this:

```
{% for skillForm in skillForms %}
   <tr class="nivEdit" style="display:none;">
       <td>{{ skillForm.skill }}</td>
       <td>{{ skillForm.skillLevel }}</td>
       <td>{{ skillForm.notes}}</td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

And the end result looks good but I don't want my user to be able to edit the skill itself, just the level and the notes. I can get the value but this is just the underlying ID of the skill model. Is there a way for me to select the shown text from the dropdown? I could do it with jquery/javascript but it would get quite messy and I would expect that there would be a solution for this in django already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the user to set level at all, just remove it from the `SkillSetEditForm.fields`. You have to add it in the view by yourself or set to `null = True, blank = True` in the model.

If you want to show skill name instead of the ID, you should add `__unicode__` method to the `Skill` model (but it's irrelevant since you remove it from the Form).

If you need this field in the form anyway, you can use Django 1.9+ Field option `disabled`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

You can try something like this in your `SkillSetEditForm` class:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  super(SkillSetEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  self.fields['skill'].disabled = True
```

Comment: I understand what you mean but I want my users to see the skill they are editing (so the name of the skill that is shown in the dropdown) and if i remove the field it won't be visible at all. There will be multiple skills on the same page so the skill name shown in the dropdown should be present. The __unicode__ is set for the skill so it does show the name in the dropdown. I just don't know how to only get the name and not the editable dropdown.

Comment: OK, then pick the object in the view and display separately. I guess you want them to edit already existing object with skill set upfront? In Django 1.9+ you can set field `disabled = True`. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#disabled

Comment: that looks like a good way to solve it but where do I add the setting to my field into my form? I only see examples where fields are added that aren't coming from the models.

Comment: You should override `__init__` in Form. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to turn some fields in model into readonly fields. As far as I know, there is no built-in way to handle this elegantly. You might completely omit the `skill` field from your form and display the relevant information by rendering the corresponding field of your model instance in the template. As an alterantive, I use the following mixin to my form class:

```
class ReadonlyMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ReadonlyMixin, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.readonly_fields = self.get_readonly_fields()
        self.disable_readonly_fields()

    def get_readonly_fields(self):
        return []

    def disable_readonly_fields(self):
        for field_name in self.readonly_fields:
                field = self.fields[field_name]
                field.required = False
                field.widget.attrs.update({'readonly': True})
                if isinstance(field, forms.ModelChoiceField):
                    selected = getattr(self.instance, field_name, None)
                    pk = selected.pk if selected else None
                    field.queryset = field.queryset.filter(pk=pk)

    def clean(self):
        self.clean_readonly_fields()

    def clean_readonly_fields(self):
        for field_name in self.readonly_fields:
            if field_name in self.fields.keys():
                self.cleaned_data[field_name] = getattr(self.instance, field_name)
```

This attaches the `readonly` attribute to the fields returned by `get_readonly_fields`, so that the corresponding inputs cannot be edited in the browser. It also restricts the choices in a select input to the selected choice. In order to prevent the user from still editing the readonly fields by manipulating the html code and sending it back to the server, `clean_readonly_fields` replaces the data received from the client with the corresponding data of the model instance.

Use the mixin like this:

```
class SkillSetEditForm(ReadonlyMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def get_readonly_fields(self):
        return ['skill']
```

Comment: thanks for your example! I still think it is really weird that django doesn't have support for this out of the box. I just need it for this one field so it really feels like a lot of work for such a small thing.

Comment: Well, actually it seems that django 1.9 does have a built-in way to do this, as @Janusz Kamieński pointed out (thanks for that!). The `disable` option seems to do something very similar. I wasn't aware of this